# How to solve this vector differential equations for simplified gravity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Long story short: I'm trying to find a position of an object in gravitational field at a specific time.

I'm doing this just 4 fun and the main goal is not to *just* find a formula, but to *understand* how this formula can be derived.
Under some constraints.
I hope this experience will help me solve other similar problems by myself.

My initial plan was to start from the classical gravity equation.
But because lack of skills and experience in calculus and differential equations I abandoned this idea.
So now I try to solve a somewhat simplified version of this.
Here are the *rules*:

1. The object is moving in $N$-dimensional space.
   $N$ might be $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ or more.
   It is very important for me to find a general solution for arbitrary number of dimensions and not stick to $2$ or $3$.
2. I expect that the *position* of an object is a **vector** function $\vec{p}(t)$ that depends only on time $t \in \mathbf{R}$.
   Just to save the space I will omit the vector notation and time argument, writing it just as $p$.
3. If $p$ is the position, then velocity is the first time derivative $p' = \dfrac{dp}{dt}$ and acceleration is second time derivative $p'' = \dfrac{d^2p}{dt^2}$. To save space I will use dot notation from physics and will write $\dot{p} = p' = \dfrac{dp}{dt}$ and $\ddot{p} = p'' = \dfrac{d^2p}{dt^2}$.
4. I don't know what is $p$ or $\dot{p}$ and the goal is to find $p$.
5. I know that at any point the object experiences an acceleration towards the center of coordinates.
   So the direction of acceleration is $-\dfrac{p}{|p|}$.
6. I also know that acceleration is four times weaker at twice the distance: inverse square.
   So the strength of acceleration is $\dfrac{1}{|p|^2}$.

All this means that acceleration is $\ddot{p} = -\dfrac{p}{|p|}\dfrac{1}{|p|^2}$.
I can rewrite this as $\ddot{p} = \dfrac{p}{|p|^3} = p|p|^{-3} = p(p^2)^{-3/2}$.
And now I can find the $p$ by taking the integral of $\ddot{p}$ twice: $\dot{p} = \int\ddot{p}dt$ and $p = \int\dot{p}dt$.
The problem is that I don't know how to do this right.

First I tried to integrate $\ddot{p}$ by substitution:

$$
\dot{p} + \dot{p}(t_0) = \int \ddot{p}dt = \int p(p^2)^{-3/2} dt
\\
u = p^2
\\
du = 2p\dot{p}dt
$$

But because $p(p^2)^{-3/2}$ lacks $2\dot{p}$ I cannot complete $du$.

I found an advice to multiply both parts by $2\dot{p}$ (dot product) and this helped to move a bit:

$$
\int 2\dot{p}\ddot{p}dt = \int 2\dot{p}p(p^2)^{-3/2} dt
\\
u = p^2
\\
du = 2p\dot{p}dt
\\
\dot{p}^2 + c = \int u^{-3/2} dt = -2u^{-1/2} = \dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{p^2}} = -2|p|^{-1}
$$

But now I completely lost the information about the acceleration vector and know only about its length.

Then I tried to integrate it by parts:

$$
\int \ddot{p}dt = \int p(p^2)^{-3/2} dt
\\
u = p
\\
du = \dot{p}dt
\\
dv = (p^2)^{-3/2}
\\
v = \int (p^2)^{-3/2} dt
$$

But now the $dv$ part doesn't want to integrate nicely.
I tried to multiply both sides by $2p\dot{p}$ scalar to preserve the vector form and be able to make substitution later:

$$
\int p 2p\dot{p}(p^2)^{-3/2} dt
\\
u = p
\\
du = \dot{p}dt
\\
dv = 2p\dot{p} (p^2)^{-3/2}
\\
v = \int 2p\dot{p} (p^2)^{-3/2} dt
\\
w = p^2
\\
dw = 2p\dot{p}
\\
\int w^{-3/2}dw = -2w^{-1/2} = -2(p^2)^{-1/2} = \dfrac{-2}{|p|}
\\
uv - \int vdu = p\dfrac{-2}{|p|} - \int \dfrac{-2}{|p|}\dot{p} dt
$$

But even after solving this:

$$
2 \int \dfrac{\dot{p}}{|p|} dt - 2 \dfrac{p}{|p|}
$$

I will have to solve the right part: $\int 2p\dot{p}\ddot{p}dt$ which doesn't look nice either.

In the end, I suspect that the object should orbit the center of coordinates on ellipse that depends on initial velocity and position. So I believe the solution should look like $p(t) = p(t_0)f(t) + \dot{p}(t_0)g(t)$ where $f$ and $g$ should be some sort of $sin$/$cos$ over $t$. But I don't see how this can be derived from initial $p(p^2)^{-3/2}$.

What am I missing? Is it even possible to solve this in **vector** from?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at some of the derivations of the Kepler laws? The fastest substitution is to first determine that the motion remains in a 2D plane, then use polar coordinates $r,\theta$ on this plane and substitute $r(t)^{-1}=u(\theta(t))$ to get a simplified differential equation for $u(\theta)$.

Comment: But how can I determine that motion remains on the plane? I mean, without already knowing the answer.
The only clue is from the $\ddot{p} = p|p|^{-3}$ that have $p$ on the second derivative just like $sin''$ has $sin$ inside of it.

Comment: And that is sufficient, as $p,\dot p$ span a 2D plane and any higher derivative can be reduced to these two using the DE.

Comment: So you're saying that I should look for a solution in a form of $pf(t) + \dot{p}g(t)$?
Or mb something like $p(t_0) f(t) + \dot{p}(t_0) g(t)$.

Comment: Yes. However, note that among all the variants of $\ddot p+c|p|^np=0$ only the variant $n=0$ and $n=-3$ give periodic solutions, apart from circular solutions. Or in other words, periodic solutions that are stable.